# Retrieve Google Now answer as string

Tags: arduino, google-now

I'm working on an Arduino project, and I would like to use the **answer** from Google Now (for example: "OK google, what time is it in Tokyo") as **string** input to be processed by Arduino (i.e. I want to get "09:15" as string).

Guidance appreciated.

Comment: That's a huge question, you need to break it down into pieces.  Are you using ethernet or wifi?  What you want is a web client, take a look at https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClient